# can not find the mistake in this proof.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$
-1=(-1)^1=(-1)^{2\frac{1}{2}}=((-1)^2)^{\frac12}=1^\frac12=1
$$
I can't find a mistake. I think it might be that $$a^{mn}=(a^m)^n$$ doesn't hold for all $$a,m,n$$ but I don't know exactly. Can anyone help?

Comment: That's exactly it. It only holds for non-negative $a$.

Comment: The square root function does not preserve sign.

Comment: @MalayTheDynamo Yes it does, it is defined for non-negative numbers only and outputs non-negative numbers only.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier True. But it doesn't here. You'd have to write $1^{\frac12}=\pm1$

Comment: @MalayTheDynamo This makes no sense. It does, period. Otherwise you're not talking about the square root **function**. Please avoid comments that can only confuse the OP.

Comment: $(a^m)^n=a^{mn}$ if i) $a$ is a non-negative real number ii) $m,n$ are integers or iii)(a more general case of ii) $m,n$ are rational numbers so that when written in fractions in the lowest terms the denominator is odd. If $m,n$ are integers and $a^m$ is $a$ multiplied by itself $m$ times then $(a^m)^n=a^{mn}$ is easily shown. If we think "well is $(a^{\frac 1m})^m=a^{\frac 1m*m}=a^1=a$ so $a^{\frac 1m}$ must be whatever $x$ is so that $x^m = a$" we have two problems: what if there is no such number?  What if there is *more* than one such number?  ... to be continued...

Comment: "what if there is no such number?  What if there is *more* than one such number?"  If $a>0$ there is always exactly one such *positive* number that is true.  So we define $a^{\frac 1m}$ as being the positive square root but *only* on a positive base.  If you look at that proof $(-a)^2=a^2$ and $(a)^2=a^2$ so to go backwards from $a^2\to ???$ we have two choices.  By definition we go back to the *positive* one.  And... that simply was not the one we started from.  So $(a^2)^{\frac 12} = a$ is simply *not* a rule we can have.  But $(a^2)^\frac 12=|a|$ so a rule we can have.

Answer (score 0):

Square roots are tricky, there are always two solutions:

$$1^{\frac{1}{2}} = \pm 1$$

So the part of the proof which goes $(-1)^1 = (-1)^{2 \frac{1}{2}}$,  introduces $1$ as a second solution.

More generally, over the reals, $$(a^2)^{\frac{1}{2}} = \pm a$$

Comment: This is intuitively true. Unfortunately, the range of the square root function is dogmatically defined as positive only.

Comment: More generally, over the reals, $\sqrt{a^2}=|a|$.  The square root *function* outputs only one output at a time, as is the case for all *functions*.  While true that $\sqrt{a^2}=a$ or $\sqrt{a^2}=-a$ for certain $a$, it is only ever equal to one of those at a time and never both (*except when $a=0$*).  *The* square root of $1$ is equal to $1$ and $1$ only.  *The* square root of $1$ is not equal to $-1$.  You seem to be confusing the square root *function* with the operator which returns the *set of roots*, a different thing and notated differently.

Comment: @DavidDiaz My mistake, see my edit. I believe the answer still applies.

Comment: @DavidDiaz The square root function is a multivalued function.  In fact, $z^w$ is defined as $e^{w\log(z)}$ where the logarithm function is defined as $\log(z)=\text{Log}(|z|)+i(\text{Arg}(z)+2n\pi)$ and $-\pi<\text{Arg}(z)\le \pi$ is the principal argument of $z$ and $\text{Log}(|z|)$ is the logarithm for real numbers.  So, for $z=1$ and $w=1/2$, we find the two values for $\sqrt{z}$ are $\pm 1$.

Comment: @MarkViola replace $\log$ with $\text{Log}$

Comment: @JMoravitz The notation should be clear, but if you wish to distinguish the complex logarithm from the logarithm for the reals, your notation suffices.

Comment: @MarkViola you seem to misunderstand my comment.  $\log$ is multivalued over complex numbers, sure.  $\text{Log}$ on the other hand is single-valued, even over the complex numbers.  I.e. force $n$ to be equal to zero in what you wrote above.

Comment: @JMoravitz I did understand.  I've even edited my comment

Comment: @MarkViola then I do not understand how you still claim that the square root function is multivalued when it returns only a single unambiguous output given an input.  I was saying to change your definition of exponentiation to $z^w:=e^{w\text{Log}(z)}$.

Comment: @JMoravitz $z^w\equiv e^{w\log(z)}=e^{w\text{Log}(|z|) +i(\text{Arg}(z)+2n\pi )w}$.  That is generally multivalued and clearly has two values for $w=1/2$ since $e^{in\pi}=(-1)^n$.

Comment: @MarkViola using the definition $z^w:=e^{w\text{Log}(z)}$ where $\text{Log}(z)$ denotes the principal logarithm results in $z^w=e^{w\text{Log}(|z|)+i\text{Arg}(z)w}$ which for $z=1,w=\frac{1}{2}$ results in $e^{0}=1$.  By completely removing $n$ from the picture, we do get unambiguous results, which gives us the nice properties that taking *the* $n$'th root is well-defined giving a single output for all numbers.  It does admittedly lead to frustrations like the OP has experienced where otherwise nice properties have specific requirements, however that is a small price to pay.

Comment: @Sebastiano I am making no further edits. Please read the other comments to see why it depends on the definition of $z^w$.

Comment: @packetpacket I have removed my comment.

Comment: Sorry for the hairsplitting :-), but $\sqrt{0}$ has only one solution. :-)

Comment: @peterh it doesn't make sense mathematically to write that $\sqrt x$ "has a solution". An equation has a solution. A number doesn't. $\sqrt x$, for non-negative real $x$, is a number, and it is **one** number.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier Right, sorry.

Comment: @peterh this is why I flagged this post for low-quality, it is so misleading. People who upvote it feel like they gain in knowledge, while the truth is they will keep writing inaccurate equalities and be confused about what the square root function is.